# Google input tools integration in android application?

Tags: android

I have been working on an android application and I am almost done with that, now I've been trying to add some additional features to it, like is there any way I can add features of Google input tools to my android app. I mean, is there any library for using Google input tools in any android app?
I know that play store has an app for Google Input Tools, and I don't want my user to install Google input tools first, but want to provide a feature so that without installing this additional app they can get Google input typing experience.
any suggestions would be helpful.
thanks in advance!!!

Comment: did u find any solution for this ?

Comment: @Shrey did you find any workaround for this ? If u can please let me know!